# if file name and directory match python

Tags: python, path, directory

I am kind of new to python so a bit confused about directory traversal. My problem is I have a folder structure like this.

```
-modules/
 -files/
  -aag
   -aag.cfg
   -something1.cfg
  -bfs
   -bfs.cfg
   -something2.cfg 
  and so on
```

In general I have to get all the cfg files under the directory

```
/modules/files/
```

The question is: I only need the config files if the directory name and the file name is the same. For example: Since aag folder has two configs I need to only get the aag.cfg file not something1.cfg.

How can I do this in python?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is only one further level of subdirectory under `/modules/files/`:

```
import os
for name in os.listdir('/modules/files'):
    config = '/modules/files/%s/%s.cfg' % (name, name)
    if os.path.isfile(config):
        # found it!
```

Comment: John, answering poorly framed questions like this encourages people to continue to ask poorly framed questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive solution that will list all directory and subdirectory which will meet your given condition.

```
import os

def foo(s):
    ans = []
    if os.path.isdir(s):
        for f in os.listdir(s):
            ans.extend(foo(s+r"/"+f))
    elif s.split(r'/')[-1].split('.')[0] == s.split(r'/')[-2]:
        ans.append(s.split(r'/')[-1])
    return ans
print(foo(r"modules")) # "modules is the directory you want to list cfg files"
```

This solution will work on the structure like this.

```
-abc/
  -abc1/
    -abc1.cfg
    -lol/
      -lol.cfg
  -pqr
    -pqr1.cfg
  -abc.cfg
```

So this code will return list

> ['abc1.cfg','lol.cfg','abc.cfg']

Comment: Thank you, for your help